# 20 natural numbers between 1 and 1000, find two subsets with the same size and sum

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{20}\}$ a set of distinct natural numbers between 1 and 1000. Prove that $\exists X,Y\subseteq A$ such that $X\cap Y = \emptyset$, $|X|=|Y|>0$, and $$\sum_{x\in X}x=\sum_{y\in Y}y$$

In my attempt to solve the problem I couldn't find the pigeons and the holes. Even a hint would do. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ is a red herring.

Suppose you have two $k$-element sets $X$ and $Y$ with the same sum, but they happen to have $\ell>0$ elements in common. Delete those $\ell$ elements, and you have two disjoint $(k-\ell)$-element sets $X \setminus Y$ and $Y \setminus X$, still with the same sum. (The sums both decrease by the sum of the deleted elements.)

Since we now want two sets with the same size and the same sum, it makes sense to look at all the $k$-element subsets of $A$ as the pigeons, with all the possible sums as the holes. (Think about which $k$ makes the most sense to use: you get to pick.)

Comment: What do you mean "you get to pick"?
There are $19600$ possible sums, ${20 \choose 5}=15504$ subsets containing $5$ numbers and ${20 \choose 6}=38760$ subsets containing $6$ numbers. Now using pigeonhole principle with subsets containing $6$ numbers as the pigeons, we're done? $5$ numbers is not enough because $$19600>15504$$ Meaning there **might** be two subsets containing $2,3,4,$ or $5$ numbers that satisfy what we need them to, but it's certain only with $6$ and above?
I'm just making sure I understand everything.

Comment: Yes, you get to pick whichever $k$ you want to make the proof work. What you're noticing is that trying to do the proof with $k=5$ doesn't work, but trying to do the proof with $k=6$ does. (I'd jump straight to $k=10$, because $\binom{20}{10}$ is huge.) (Also, $k=5$ does work if you notice that there are fewer than $5000$ possible sums of only $5$ elements.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!